# Get the path of a directory using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

How can I get the absolute path of a directory using JFileChooser, just selecting the directory?

Comment: See the documentation. Getting the java.io.File: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29).  Selecting only directories: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use:

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
//or
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

together with:

```
chooser.getCurrentDirectory()
//or
chooser.getSelectedFile();
```

then call `getAbsoluteFile()` on the `File` object returned.

Answer (score 8):

`JFileChooser`'s `getSelectedFile()` method, returns a [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object.
Use the `getAbsolutePath()` to get the absolute name to the file.

modified example from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html):

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this directory: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

System.out.println(fullPath);
```

fullPath gives you the required Absolute path of the Selected directory