# Returning full directory path in String variable (JAVA)

Tags: java, file

I am trying to use the JFileChooser to have the user select a file.  The absolute directory then needs to be in a string variable so I can use it in later code.  So far, I have not found any solution/tips anywhere else online.  So far I have...

```
FileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Image to detect facial presence");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the path of a directory using JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444508/get-the-path-of-a-directory-using-jfilechooser)

Comment: Sir(@RobertMoskal) OP is using both the important  things  as mentioned in the above link. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Get the path of a directory using JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444508/get-the-path-of-a-directory-using-jfilechooser) as indicated by [@RobertMoskal's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735360/returning-full-directory-path-in-string-variable-java#comment80417372_46735360):

```
FileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Image to detect facial presence");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);

int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

//ADDITIONAL CODE
String filePath;
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); //<<<<<
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
          "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
      chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Select Image to detect facial presence");
      chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
      String temp;
      int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      temp = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: You forgot to check for `APPROVE_OPTION`, as the chooser's dialog may also be cancelled or error-out. Other than that, our answers are pretty much identical (I also fixed the indentation and gave proper credits, but meh).